# Custom authentication in Django

Tags: python, django, authentication

Does anybody know what problem it might be. I'm doing custom authentication in order to use token authentication without passing username but email adres instead, during first login. When I run first makemigrations I constantly get

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'main.User' that has not been installed

I'm pretty sure I have app of that name in installed app.

[Tutorial I've mentioned about](https://thinkster.io/tutorials/django-json-api/authentication)

My folders str:

```
+---main
|   +---migrations
+---squanchy_learn_rest_api
```

models.py:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from django.conf import settings

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser):
    objects = UserManager()
    username = None
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True,)
    password_2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True,)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    # The `USERNAME_FIELD` property tells us which field we will use to log in.
    # In this case we want it to be the email field.
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    # UserManager class defined above should manage
    # objects of this type.
    # For getting more info about overriding methods visit:
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.name
```

settings.py:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '9y&q=wo&g#ylm@p(kn@1!)=5d%q^%kz*^#9a4ns#tusov&$xr1'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'djoser',
    'main',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'squanchy_learn_rest_api.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'squanchy_learn_rest_api.wsgi.application'

# AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.User'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',),
}

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'main.User'


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Warsaw'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Full(almost) folders and files structure:

```
C:.
│   manage.py
│   Pipfile
│   Pipfile.lock
│
├───.idea
│   │   .gitignore
│   │   misc.xml
│   │   modules.xml
│   │   squanchy-lean-rest-api-2.iml
│   │   vcs.xml
│   │   workspace.xml
│   │
│   └───inspectionProfiles
│           profiles_settings.xml
│
├───main
│   │   admin.py
│   │   apps.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   serializers.py
│   │   tests.py
│   │   views.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───migrations
│   │   │   __init__.py
│   │   │
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   │           __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   │
│   └───__pycache__
│           admin.cpython-38.pyc
│           models.cpython-38.pyc
│           serializers.cpython-38.pyc
│           tests.cpython-38.pyc
│           views.cpython-38.pyc
│           __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│
└───squanchy_learn_rest_api
    │   settings.py
    │   urls.py
    │   wsgi.py
    │   __init__.py
    │
    └───__pycache__
            settings.cpython-38.pyc
            urls.cpython-38.pyc
            wsgi.cpython-38.pyc
            __init__.cpython-38.pyc
```

Comment: post your models.py and settings.py

Comment: The most common reason for this error:
when you accidently mentioned your app name in MIDDLEWARE instead of INSTALLED_APPS, go in your settings.py file and check for this issue.

Comment: @GrandPhuba I've added models and settings.

Comment: @ wadleo  I've added models and settings

Comment: @DominikBasista I haven't looked into it closely so this more of a shot in the dark, but have you tried renaming the app from something else not `main`?

Comment: @GrandPhuba Yes I did

Comment: @DominikBasista can you post your full folder structure from the root project, thanks.

Comment: @ wadleo I added full folders/files structue

Comment: @DominikBasista I can't find a main app, I think the AUTH_USER_MODEL should be set to account.User. Please try that and let me know

Comment: Mistakenly, I've added wrong files structure(from other project).  I updated to right one. Sorry about that @wadleo